# root\\CIMV2, select * from Win32_***. Где взять информацию о таблицах Win32_***. C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Хочу написать одно приложение на c#, которое выдает информацию о ПК. Пошарив интернеты, нашел такую вещь `System.Management`. Так вот там, чтобы получить, например, список служб, используют такое создание объекта

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher3 = 
new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");
```

Так вот, где взять список вот этих таблиц, к которым идет обращение за информацией.

Пока что нашел только 2:

- `Win32_Service` - таблица со службами
- `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` - таблица с сетевыми интерфейсами.

Можно сслыку, где взять остальные таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WMI Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394572(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Operating System Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792258(v=vs.85).aspx)

[WQL (SQL for WMI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx)

Для быстрого поиска нужного класса и его свойства с построением кода рекомендую [WMI Code Creator 1.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572) (как вариант - [WMI Code Creator For Windows Forms for VB.NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380148/WMI-Code-Creator-For-Windows-Forms-For-VB-Net)) или [Scriptomatic 2.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd939957.aspx).

Comment: Спасибо большое:)